# Java - NoClassDefFoundError although the class exists

Tags: java, class

I'm still very new to Java. I'm trying to use CMU's Sphinx4 voice recognition. When I used the compiling process they have prepared, everything worked fine. However, now that I'm trying to compile my own code separately I'm running into a problem.

In the codes source files (src/) exists an apps/ directory which contains the demos I'm trying to compile manually, along with a sphinx4/ directory which contains the main functions to be used. To compile the code I move into the apps/ directory and run
 `javac -classpath ../sphinx4/ edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/helloworld/HelloWorld.java`. This compiles without error. However, then when I try to run the newly made class using `java edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/helloworld/HelloWorld` the result is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/cmu/sphinx/util/props/ConfigurationManager
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.helloworld.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 1 more
```

Yet, as far as I can tell, the class does exist right where it should be. src/sphinx4/edu/cmu/sphinx/util/props/ConfigurationManager.class exists. I'm guessing there is a good reason that it is considered not found when it is there, but I just don't know it because I don't know enough about Java yet. What might cause this to happen?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

- You need to specify the classpath when you *run* as well as when you compile
- You need to specify a *class name* to run; that won't have slashes in

You want:

```
java -classpath .:../sphinx4 edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.helloworld.HelloWorld
```

Use ";" instead of ":" if you're running on Windows.

(Your error message suggests that you actually *are* giving the right class name, in which case your question hasn't really shown what you're doing. It's important to be accurate in your question, in order to get helpful answers.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! (Sorry I was not quicker in replying).

I'm using linux, which is why I'm using the colon.

I double checked and these are indeed the exact commands I'm using. Where would I be using the class name instead? When I use the "java" command?

I will try including the classpath when running as well. Hopefully that will fix the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, once I added the classpath when running, then it resulted in an error with the fact that I was not using the class name. So I had posted correctly what I was doing above, but indeed you are correct that I need to use the class name when running instead.

Comment: @golmschenk: If you didn't use the correct class name, I'm *extremely* surprised that the stack trace showed any sign if of it finding the `HelloWorld` class at all...

Comment: And finally, after adding the class name correctly it now gets past that error. I'm at a new one now, but I'll see about fixing that one myself before bringing it here. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I don't know enough about java yet to tell you what I might have done strangely. I just copied and pasted my command from my terminal to my post. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Look:
Note 4:

> If you have the source distribution, make sure that the JAR file lib/sphinx4.jar is built. If not, go to the top level directory and type: ant.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) to build the project with your new class(es).

Did you follow the instructions here: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/#how_build ?

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I did follow those instructions during the initial setup. And through that the demos worked fine. However, I'm now working to create an files outside of the sphinx directory and I was planning on manually compiling them there. To figure out what was going wrong there though I decided I should try to manually compile the existing demos. Should I be using ant for my own external files as well somehow? Thanks!

Comment: Yeps, according to me you should keep ant to build and package the whole application.

Comment: Cool cool. I'll look into to using that as well then. Thanks!